# Unity - GameObject won't destroyed when hit a prefab

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, destroy, gameobject

In the game you controll a ball (Sphere) and two types of boxes falling down: deathCube and goldCube. When the Sphere hit the DeathCube, then the Sphere is destroyt, but it not get destroyed and I don't know why. The cubes are prefabs and they have a tag(DeathCube, GoldCube).

```
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "DeathCube") 
    {
        Destroy (gameObject);
    }
}   

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "GoldCube") 
    {
        gold++;
    }
}
```

If the Sphere hit the goldCube you get points, but this doesn't work too.

Comment: Does your code reach `Destroy(gameObject)` line? Have you put breakpoint/log there?

Comment: Yes, and it's also added in the Inspector     public GameObject sphere;

Comment: Is your sphere collider marked `IsTrigger`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you don't have a rigidbody attached to at least one of the objects in the collision (ball or cube), then the trigger event won't be initiated.**

From the documentation:

> Notes: Trigger events are only sent if one of the colliders also has a rigidbody attached

Source: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter.html

Comment: That was the problem, after I triggered the the object it's worked

Answer (score 2):

Try merging the two OnTriggerEnter's into one.

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "DeathCube") 
    {
        Destroy (gameObject);
    }

    if (other.gameObject.tag == "GoldCube") 
    {
        gold++;
    }
}
```

I believe that the second one is overriding the first, never allowing the `Destroy()` to be called. I would've assumed the compiler would throw an error with this, but you don't seem to have indicated that.

Comment: Glad I could help! It's often the stupid mistakes that keep me preoccupied the most when I'm programming, so it gets easier to spot it in other's code.